# Pros and Cons of programming languages for XML & string manipulation

Tags: xml, string, programming-languages, server-side

I don't mean this to be opinionated.

What are serious pros/cons of various server-side languages in regards to creating/modifying xml. I'm currently researching new platform/language direction and we deal with a lot of xml.

We also do a lot of string manipulation, what advantages/disadvantages do different languages have in regards to string manipulation. I'm thinking along the lines of regular expression searching and replacing.

Comment: You may want to be careful about regular expressions for XML. How would you distinguish between tag names and text values? XPath is probably a better way to go..

Comment: The analyze-string tag (I mentioned below) for XSL combines XPath via the select attribute and RegEx via the regex attribute, to isolate the  data from the meta-data.  This is how you could distinguish between tag names and text values.

Comment: @vtd-xml-author the regular expressions are not for the xml, the software I work with does a lot of string manipulation, that is where the regular expressions are used. I would definitely use xpath for xml :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as XML goes, no language really has an edge. There are multiple libraries for pretty much every language out there, and lots have LibXML bindings.

For string manipulation, Perl might have an edge as it has very convenient regular expression syntax along with handy methods such as `tr` and `lc` … but that could just be my Perl bias showing through.

In the end — go with the languages you are familiar with.

Comment: "In the end - go with the languages you are familiar with." -- I couldn't disagree more.  You wouldn't pound in nails with a screw driver because you are more familiar with it, even though it might work.  Why would you use a language (which is just a tool) to transform xml text if there is a language out there specifically for that task?

Comment: @dacracot Couldn't agree with you more. Granted if two languages are similar in efficiency, and your team is familiar with one, you should probably go that route.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out VB.NETs XML Literal functionality

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364068(VS.80).aspx#vb9overview_topic6

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Scala.  It has built in support for XML literals and also good regex support.

Examples:
   http://ikaisays.com/2009/04/04/using-pattern-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-scala/
   http://joeygibson.com/2009/09/24/im-liking-scalas-xml-literals/

If you have enterprise dollars, Tibco BusinessWorks works really good for handling XML also with GUI xpath expressions and xml to its core.

---

I'm sure an argument can be made for almost any language.  It may come down to what language you are comfortable with and can easily find skilled developers for.

Comment: Again the "what language you are comfortable with" argument!  See above.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely consider [The Extensible Stylesheet Language Family (XSL)](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/).  This language is specifically designed to manipulate XML.  You can use regular expression in XSL via [`<xsl:analyze-string select="" regex="">`](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1222).